# Consistent vertical alignment of one-line text in minipages

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

The vertical alignment of one-line text in minipages depends on the vertical extent of the text itself:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
  bad alignment:
  \frame{
  \begin{minipage}[c][1cm][c]{0.1\linewidth}
    \LARGE Good
  \end{minipage}}
  \frame{
  \begin{minipage}[c][1cm][c]{0.2\linewidth}
     \LARGE Morning
  \end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

[image: bad alignment]

There is a simple solution adding a full extent dummy symbol like `\ddag`, but I don't like this solution for different reasons (e.g. bad for people who want to copy the text from my pdf as they will copy my hidden dummy symbol as well):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
  dummy symbol solution:
  \frame{
  \begin{minipage}[c][1cm][c]{0.1\linewidth}
    \LARGE Good\textcolor{white}{\ddag}
  \end{minipage}}
  \frame{
  \begin{minipage}[c][1cm][c]{0.2\linewidth}
    \LARGE Morning\textcolor{white}{\ddag}
  \end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Do you have any advices how to solve this problem?

Comment: Usually in such cases what I does is to add `\vphantom{g}` in the definition of `\end{...}`. This will be a problem when we use boxes.

Comment: Use `\strut` instead of a whitened character. However, `\frame` is an undocumented macro and probably you should use `\fbox`

Comment: @Jagath : Thanks for this comment. Could you explain it a little more in detail, maybe as an answer? For example: 1st. I didn't redefine `\end` before. 2nd. I didn't use `\vphantom` before - doesn't it leave a hidden symbol which I can copy as well?

Comment: @egreg : Thank you for this hint. The `\frame` is just for the visualization of the minipage extent here.

Comment: @matheburg How come your minipage environment has all those extra options? That doesn't match up with the specification given on this page: http://www.public.asu.edu/~rjansen/latexdoc/ltx-267.html

Comment: @JohnWickerson Those optional arguments are not very much known, but they are legal and useful.

Comment: @JohnWickerson : Take a look e.g. [here](http://www.sascha-frank.com/latex-minipage.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about the `\frame{...}` command you're using, but it seems that `\fbox{...}` is the one you want for this purpose: it makes the baseline of its contents respect the baseline of its environment.

Also, as Jagath AR has suggested, you can use `\vphantom{...}` rather than white text. Simpler still, you can use `\strut`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent 
  With struts:
  \fbox{
  \begin{minipage}[t]{16mm}
    \LARGE Good\strut
  \end{minipage}}
  \fbox{
  \begin{minipage}[t]{23mm}
    \LARGE Morning\strut
  \end{minipage}}
  Without struts:
  \fbox{
  \begin{minipage}[t]{16mm}
    \LARGE Good
  \end{minipage}}
  \fbox{
  \begin{minipage}[t]{23mm}
    \LARGE Morning
  \end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you - this is the beautiful solution I was looking for! Nevertheless, the extended `minipage` options would make your solution looking much better ;-)