# Alignment of minipage environment off when using enumitem

Tags: minipage, enumitem

The vertical alignment in the minipage alignment is off when using enumitem.  If I remove all enumitem coding the vertical alignment is fine.  How can I force the minipage boxes to align equally along the top?

Unrelated to enumitem (with all enumitem coding removed), the horizontal alignment is not aligned either.

Is tabular a better way to achieve this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
\fbox
{
\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
\item text
\end{minipage}
}
\fbox
{
\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text
\end{minipage}
}\\
\fbox
{\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
\item text
\end{minipage}
}
\fbox
{\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text
\end{minipage}
}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: enumerate should be a list of `\item` using `\fbox` and `minipage` can not work, especially minipage  as that sets up normalised "page" setting so losing list setup

Comment: I am trying to make a numbered list of question and answers using the package enumitem, organized so that students can cut and paste each and turn into flash cards.  The above does compile, it's just that the alignment is slightly off and looks odd. If you start the enumitem before the minipage environment, and end enumitem after you end minipage, it works.

Comment: I know you get no error but any output is more or less accidental, latex lists really are not designed for this.

Comment: How should I best achieve what I am trying to do then?  A related question is then, how would one do numbered lists in a table?

Comment: probably get rid of the eumerate and replace `\item` by a command defined as `\refstepcounter{enumi}\arabic{enumi}) ` so it's simple text not  list spacing confused by being in a minipage

Comment: Thanks, that is working nicely in so far as numbering in minipages and tabular formats.  However, this has revealed a new problem unrelated to enumitem.  I'll start a new question topic to address this alignment problem in minipage.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my alignment problem was not related to enumitem at all.  The solution to this problem can be found here: [Consistent vertical alignment of one-line text in minipages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124082/consistent-vertical-alignment-of-one-line-text-in-minipages)

Using \strut and     \refstepcounter{enumi}\arabic{enumi}):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\fbox
{
\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
\refstepcounter{enumi}\arabic{enumi}) text\strut
\end{minipage}
}
\fbox
{
\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text\strut
\end{minipage}
}\\
\fbox
{\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
\refstepcounter{enumi}\arabic{enumi}) text\strut
\end{minipage}
}
\fbox
{\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text\strut
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```